# How do I print the second output without duplicating any of the first output?

Tags: python, random, duplicates, sample

It is because I cannot pick the same players as my friend. He is the first output and I am the second output. Below is what I have.

```
import random

players = ('Giannis', 'LeBron', 'KD', 'Curry', 'Harden', 'AD', 'RW', 'Kawhi', 'Lillard', 'Kyrie', 'PG13',
                        'Klay', 'Jimmy', 'Dwyane', 'Blake', 'MJ', 'KarlAnthony', 'BenSim', 'JohnW', 'Melo')

c_starting5 = random.sample(players, k=5)
i_starting5 = random.sample(players, k=5)

c = c_starting5
i = i_starting5

print(c)
print(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code as a code segment, this way, people cant copy-and-paste the code to run it themselves. You can do that by indenting or by enclosing your code with three backticks - there is an example in the editing screen below the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want 10 unique random players divided into two groups of five (with all the players still being unique between the two groups), I'd suggest taking a sample of 10 and then slicing it:

```
pool = random.sample(players, 10)
i_starting5, c_starting5 = pool[:5], pool[5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I understand it is that you want the second player to not be able to choose any players that the first player has chosen.

One way of accomplishing this is to build a new list of players that do not include the players already selected. You can change your i_starting5 to the following.

This sample uses list comprehension to create a new list of players that have not already been selected

```
import random

players = ('Giannis', 'LeBron', 'KD', 'Curry', 'Harden', 'AD', 'RW', 'Kawhi', 'Lillard', 'Kyrie', 'PG13', 'Klay', 'Jimmy', 'Dwyane', 'Blake', 'MJ', 'KarlAnthony', 'BenSim', 'JohnW', 'Melo')

c_starting5 = random.sample(players, k=5)
i_starting5 = random.sample([p for p in players if not(p in c_starting5)], k=5)

c = c_starting5
i = i_starting5

print(c)
print(i)
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the line, you just added it before the printing. I think you need to understand how the code works a bit more. Try using the debugger to see what the values are after each line is run.

Comment: I have tried adding that line and it is still the same problem. Duplicating the first output in the second output after a few runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a random sample of the `players` stored in `i_starting5` and they are not stored in `c_starting5` then I think the code you need is this:

```
import random

players = ('Giannis', 'LeBron', 'KD', 'Curry', 'Harden', 'AD', 'RW', 'Kawhi', 'Lillard', 'Kyrie', 'PG13',
                        'Klay', 'Jimmy', 'Dwyane', 'Blake', 'MJ', 'KarlAnthony', 'BenSim', 'JohnW', 'Melo')

c_starting5 = random.sample(players, k=5)

left_players = list(set(players) - set(c_starting5)) # This line added

i_starting5 = random.sample(left_players, k=5) # players changed to left_players

c = c_starting5
i = i_starting5

print(c)
print(i)
```

Clarification:
I subtracted the original `player` from the first sample `c_starting5` of 5 and stored the difference in `left_players` then I took the other sample of 5 from that difference (which will not have any element from the first sample)

Comment: I changed it up a bit and it is still the same problem. import random

players = ('Giannis', 'LeBron', 'KD', 'Curry', 'Harden', 'AD', 'RW', 'Kawhi', 'Lillard', 'Kyrie', 'PG13',
                        'Klay', 'Jimmy', 'Dwyane', 'Blake', 'MJ', 'KarlAnthony', 'BenSim', 'JohnW', 'Melo')

c_starting5 = random.sample(players, k=5)

left_players = list(set(players) - set(c_starting5))

left_players = random.sample(players, k=5)

#i_starting5 = random.sample(players, k=5)

print(c_starting5)
print(left_players)

Comment: I added the comment at the line below it `players changed to left_players` which telling to `i_starting5` to take the random sample from the `left_players` not from the original players tuple